# How can write values in Registry while installing VB.net application?

Tags: vb.net, installation, registry

I want to make use of **registry to store installation date**.

This would allow me to **check application expiry on each run**, so when I install my application on any PC the registry subkey will be created and store current date as installation date.

I am **using Visual Studio Installer Set up** and Deployment.

If you have any other suggestion to achieve this, please share.

Comment: Yes i have suggestion, show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: This is a bad idea and is easily defeated, especially the part about updating it each time

Comment: @Plutonix I would agree.

Comment: Actually I want to write in registry while I am installing and checking the registry on every application run, I requested if you have any suggestion please share thanks. I have no idea how can i do it with msi.

Comment: What are you using to create your installer?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Installer Set up and Deployment.

Comment: The only reason to do that sort of thing is to prevent users circumventing the use of a trial version of your app or the like.  In that case, invest in a proper licensing component.  Anything you do yourself, including what you've suggested, will be all but useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general answer, create a registry item and put the appropriate Windows Installer property there, in this case [Date] in square brackets, case-sensitive, just like you'd put [TARGETDIR] to record the installation folder. This avoids code.

However it is a bad idea, as the comments point out. Apart from the fact that it can be defeated, the poor person that installs it then can't use it for a week is in trouble. You should start the clock on first run of the app. That's fair and accurate.

Otherwise, give each user something unique, maybe a license key, and have the app call into your company's web service on first run, saying "this key started now", then you can check every time the app runs and say no after the timer has expired, then you're using your company's clock, not the user's.